# PyQt using Qthread but the main thread still can't go on

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, pyside, pyside2, pyqt6

I have created a Pyqt application like this:

[image: mainwindow]

the function of this application is that when I push the button 'pushButton', it starts a function to calculate 0+1+...+1000000 on the background; meanwhile the mainwindow pops up a loading dialog which means that the function is being operated.

I use QThread to fulfill the request above, the main thread 'MainWindow' is made to pop up the loading dialog, while the thread 'WorkThread' is made to calculate 0+1+...+1000000：

```py
# thread
class WorkThread(QThread):
    imgProcessSignal = Signal()

    def __init__(self):
        QThread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        self.imgProcessSignal.emit()

# pop up dialog
class LoadingDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        movie = QMovie(':\icons\images\icons\loading.gif')
        self.ui.label_2.setMovie(movie)
        self.ui.label_2.setScaledContents(False)
        movie.start()
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.show()


# main window
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()  # create your own UI object
        self.ui.setupUi(self)  # set all the attributes of object[self]

        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.buttonClick)

        self.show()

    def buttonClick(self):
        btn = self.sender()
        btnName = btn.objectName()

        if btnName == 'pushButton':
            self.dialog = LoadingDialog()
            self.thread1 = WorkThread()
            self.thread1.imgProcessSignal.connect(self.calculate)
            self.thread1.start()

    def calculate(self):
        sum = 0
        for i in range(100000000):
            sum += i
```

but when I run the application, the result is like the gif below:

[image]

the problem is that I cannot do anything on this poping up dialog and the loading.gif can't implement animation effect, it seems that only when the 'WorkThread' is finished can I operate on this dialog(e.g:close the dialog) and the loading.gif is not shown correctly.

Is there anything wrong with my use of Qthread?

I wonder how I can make the background thread and the main thread work respectively and correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your thread doesn't do any actual processing. The `calculate()` function is still being executed in the main thread.
You must put the calculate logic in the worker thread. Either in `run()` or define the `calculate()` method in the thread and call it from `run()`

All your worker thread does is immediately emit a signal when it starts. Connecting that signal to a method in the main thread doesn't make that method run in the worker thread.

Also, You don't have to override `__init__` if you don't add anything beyond a call to the parent class.